# rails - how to make nested route with ancestry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-routes, ancestry

I have a single model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_ancestry
    validates :slug, :name, uniqueness: true, presence: true
    before_validation :generate_slug

    def to_param
        slug
    end

    def generate_slug
        self.slug = Russian.translit(name).parameterize
    end
end
```

and I'm using `ancestry` gem to create tree of pages and subpages, i.e. page can have multiple sub-pages and sub-pages can also have multiple sub-pages, and so on to infinity.

But my problem is that I can't make something is `/page-1/page-1-2/page-1-2-1`. All sub-pages have a URL is: `/page-1-2` or `/page-1-3-1`.

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get '/pages' => 'pages#index'

    resources :pages, path: "", path_names: { new: 'add' }

    root 'pages#index'
end
```

How to make nested URL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there's no neat way of capturing nested tree structured routes with dynamic permalinks, you can create a named route to capture pretty nested pages path:

```
get '/p/*id', :to => 'pages#show', :as => :nested_pages
```

Also, make sure you update `slug` of your page object to have nested urls, i.e.: append parent pages' `slug` to it. For example:

```
page1.slug = '/page-1'
page2.slug = '/page-1/page-2' # page2 is a child of page1
page3.slug = '/page-1/page-2/page-3' # page3 is a child of page2
```

So, to make this work, you can probably change `generate_slug` method in your `Page` model class:

```
def generate_slug
  name_as_slug = Russian.translit(name).parameterize
  if parent.present?
    self.slug = [parent.slug, (slug.blank? ? name_as_slug : slug.split('/').last)].join('/')
  else
    self.slug = name_as_slug if slug.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: It's works, thx! But when I want to edit something subpage, I catched error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` and `Parameters: {"slug"=>"page-1/page-1-1/page-1-1-1/page-1-1-1-1/edit"}`. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use `Page.find_by_slug(params['slug'])`. Also, don't forget to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if it helps.

Comment: Sorry) Yes, I used it `find_by_slug` but I all the same catch this error.

Comment: Ok, I solved this problem. Now I can't update the slug after changed the record. The slug remains such as was :(